# Generate constant during setup

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup.py, distutils

Is there a way, short of code generation, to generate a constant during build/install which can be referenced at run-time?

Specifically, I'd like to retain the path the package was built out of, but I suppose there might be a more general answer.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not clear. Can you edit your question and give us an example?

Comment: I don't have an example because I'm not sure how to do this. I want to define a constant in `setup.py` and reference it during runtime after it's installed with pip.

Comment: I'm asking if it's possible, and if so how or what is the best practice, not why my current code isn't working.

Comment: `setup.py` is arbitrary code -- so yes it's possible

Comment: Best way IMO would be extending package metadata with own keywords and values, but the [current metadata version 2.1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0566) doesn't allow it (yet?). Write a simple config file (e.g. in a custom `build`/`sdist` command impl) and include it into distribution, should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Yes.

Arrange for `setup.py` to write `const.txt`,
ship that as part of your package,
and `open()` the file to read it in your constructor.